# Multiple image selection from Android device gallery with xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-gallery

Following is my code to select multiple image from gallery. But don't know why its not working. I am able to select only one image at a time from gallery. But from Recent items I am able to select multiple images.I want to select multiple items from gallery also. so what changes I should made for that?

```
        var imageIntent = new Intent ();
        imageIntent.SetType ("image/*");
        imageIntent.SetAction (Intent.ActionPick);
        imageIntent.PutExtra (Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple,true);
        StartActivityForResult (Intent.CreateChooser (imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to implement multi-selection of images in gallery:

1. Intent for getting multiple images
2. Define custom gallery with fetching and loading photos from native gallery.

Try out this Samples :

- https://github.com/PareshMayani/Gallery-MultiPhotoSelect
- http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/